# UITableView embedded in UITableViewCell is not getting actual contentSize.height on reloading

Tags: uitableview, ios-autolayout

I have a UITableView and a UIButton embedded in UITableViewCell. On tapping on the button I'm reloading the height of the table view  from 0 to tableView.contentSize.height. The content size is coming proper but the cell's height is overriding the table view height. Any solutions?